# Python ffmpeg diffence in scaling file size

Tags: ffmpeg

```
def crop(input_file, output_file, x, y):
    subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', input_file, '-filter:v', 'scale=.{}/{}*iw:ih'.format(x, y), output_file])

crop('C:/home/filename.m4v', 'C:/home/filename.mp4', 320, 240)
```

The file converts okay but the file size is quite a bit bigger as compared to when I

`ffmpeg -i filename.m4v -vf scale=320:240 filename.mp4`

```
original file=3523
python=3765
command line=1

888
```

If I take the python version and convert it with the command line=1872

Why the discrepancy? I'm trying to both change the file size and in most cases hopefully save disk space. What do I have to do to get the smaller file size with python? I have hundreds of videos I want to convert and this will make it much more automated/faster than do it with the command line.

EDIT BELOW:
I decided to try with a different video and see what the comparisons would be.

Using:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T1tV-ovGPyc
```

I downloaded both the 480 and 360 version to compare original file size and to compare when I did the resizing, both with the command line and with python.

480 = 215.924 Mb
360 = 170.333 Mb

When converted with the command line:

```
ffmpeg -i filename.mp4 scale=320:240 filename1.mp4
```

480 = 116.488 Mb
360 = 115.454 Mb

When I use python:

```
subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', input_file, '-crf:23', 'scale=.{}/{}*iw:ih'.format(x, y), output_file])
```

480 = 264.509 Mb
360 = 193.640 Mb

Changing it to -crf:50 python based:

480 = 264.509 Mb
360 = 193.640 Mb

Not sure if I could try changing command line to -crf:50 and keep the scale at 320:240 or not. My quick attempts kept giving me back an error 'Unable to find a suitable output format for 'scale=320:240''

Here is the full setup/end log when using the command line(360 file mentioned above)

```
ffmpeg version N-105780-g0d0002cd20-20220227 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers

  built with gcc 11.2.0 (crosstool-NG 1.24.0.533_681aaef)

  configuration: --prefix=/ffbuild/prefix --pkg-config-flags=--static --pkg-config=pkg-config --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --arch=x86_64 --target-os=mingw32 --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-debug --disable-w32threads --enable-pthreads --enable-iconv --enable-libxml2 --enable-zlib --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-fontconfig --enable-libvorbis --enable-opencl --disable-libpulse --enable-libvmaf --disable-libxcb --disable-xlib --enable-amf --enable-libaom --enable-avisynth --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --disable-libfdk-aac --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-frei0r --enable-libgme --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librist --enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-lv2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-schannel --enable-sdl2 --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtwolame --enable-libuavs3d --disable-libdrm --disable-vaapi --enable-libvidstab --enable-vulkan --enable-libshaderc --enable-libplacebo --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzvbi --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-cxxflags= --extra-ldflags=-pthread --extra-ldexeflags= --extra-libs=-lgomp --extra-version=20220227

  libavutil      57. 21.100 / 57. 21.100

  libavcodec     59. 21.100 / 59. 21.100

  libavformat    59. 17.102 / 59. 17.102

  libavdevice    59.  5.100 / 59.  5.100

  libavfilter     8. 27.100 /  8. 27.100

  libswscale      6.  5.100 /  6.  5.100

  libswresample   4.  4.100 /  4.  4.100

  libpostproc    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100

Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'filename.mp4':

  Metadata:

    major_brand     : mp42

    minor_version   : 0

    compatible_brands: isommp42

    creation_time   : 2018-06-06T01:11:10.000000Z

  Duration: 00:42:39.05, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 544 kb/s

  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt709, progressive), 540x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 3:2], 446 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn (default)

    Metadata:

      creation_time   : 2018-06-06T01:11:10.000000Z

      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. 

Created on: 06/05/2018.

      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]

  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 95 kb/s (default)

    Metadata:

      creation_time   : 2018-06-06T01:11:10.000000Z

      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. 

Created on: 06/05/2018.

      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]

Stream mapping:

  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))

  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))

Press [q] to stop, [?] for help

[libx264 @ 000002996b8a90c0] using SAR=9/8

[libx264 @ 000002996b8a90c0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2

[libx264 @ 000002996b8a90c0] profile High, level 1.3, 4:2:0, 8-bit

[libx264 @ 000002996b8a90c0] 264 - core 164 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2022 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: 
cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=7 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00

Output #0, mp4, to 'filename1.mp4':

  Metadata:

    major_brand     : mp42

    minor_version   : 0

    compatible_brands: isommp42

    encoder         : Lavf59.17.102

  Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt709, progressive), 320x240 [SAR 9:8 DAR 3:2], q=2-31, 29.97 fps, 30k tbn (default)

    Metadata:

      creation_time   : 2018-06-06T01:11:10.000000Z

      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. 
Created on: 06/05/2018.

      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]

      encoder         : Lavc59.21.100 libx264

    Side data:

      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)

    Metadata:

      creation_time   : 2018-06-06T01:11:10.000000Z

      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. 
Created on: 06/05/2018.

      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]

      encoder         : Lavc59.21.100 aac

frame=76693 fps=454 q=-1.0 Lsize=  115454kB time=00:42:39.04 bitrate= 369.6kbits/s speed=15.2x

video:73329kB audio:39501kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 2.325049%

[libx264 @ 000002996b8a90c0] frame I:462   Avg QP:20.30  size: 13259

[libx264 @ 000002996b8a90c0] frame P:30634 Avg QP:23.42  size:  1629

[libx264 @ 000002996b8a90c0] frame B:45597 Avg QP:28.92  size:   418

[libx264 @ 000002996b8a90c0] consecutive B-frames: 17.7%  7.0%  6.5% 68.8%

[libx264 @ 000002996b8a90c0] mb I  I16..4:  6.8% 50.1% 43.0%

[libx264 @ 000002996b8a90c0] mb P  I16..4:  1.1%  3.5%  0.9%  P16..4: 27.7% 13.2%  8.8%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:44.8%

[libx264 @ 000002996b8a90c0] mb B  I16..4:  0.1%  0.4%  0.2%  B16..8: 31.0%  5.4%  1.3%  direct: 1.5%  skip:60.2%  L0:39.0% L1:50.2% BI:10.9%

[libx264 @ 000002996b8a90c0] 8x8 transform intra:60.1% inter:58.6%

[libx264 @ 000002996b8a90c0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 62.2% 55.5% 24.7% inter: 12.3% 9.1% 0.8%

[libx264 @ 000002996b8a90c0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 22% 38%  9% 31%

[libx264 @ 000002996b8a90c0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 17% 24% 20%  5%  6%  6%  9%  5%  8%

[libx264 @ 000002996b8a90c0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 18% 24% 13%  6%  8%  7% 10%  6%  8%

[libx264 @ 000002996b8a90c0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 59% 21% 15%  5%

[libx264 @ 000002996b8a90c0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:7.2% UV:3.0%

[libx264 @ 000002996b8a90c0] ref P L0: 71.3% 14.3% 10.4%  3.7%  0.3%

[libx264 @ 000002996b8a90c0] ref B L0: 92.5%  6.1%  1.5%

[libx264 @ 000002996b8a90c0] ref B L1: 96.2%  3.8%

[libx264 @ 000002996b8a90c0] kb/s:234.74

[aac @ 000002996c0dcdc0] Qavg: 3985.249
```

This is the python setup only message using:

```
subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', input_file, '-filter:v', 'scale=.{}/{}*iw:ih'.format(x, y), output_file])

[libx264 @ 0000029d2d338e00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2

[libx264 @ 0000029d2d338e00] profile High, level 3.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit

[libx264 @ 0000029d2d338e00] 264 - core 164 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2022 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=11 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00

Output #0, mp4, to 'C:/filename1.mp4':

  Metadata:

    major_brand     : mp42

    minor_version   : 0

    compatible_brands: isommp42

    encoder         : Lavf59.17.102

  Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt709, progressive), 540x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 3:2], q=2-31, 29.97 fps, 30k tbn (default)

    Metadata:

      creation_time   : 2018-06-06T01:11:10.000000Z

      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 06/05/2018.

      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]

      encoder         : Lavc59.21.100 libx264

    Side data:

      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A

  Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)

    Metadata:

      creation_time   : 2018-06-06T01:11:10.000000Z

      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 06/05/2018.

      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]

      encoder         : Lavc59.21.100 aac
```

Comment: I have tried the same set of procedures with around 10 videos and everytime the same thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to achieve a certain level of compression (or file size) you need to specify your target. If you are outputting MP4 with H.264 video codec, read [this FFmpeg Wiki entry](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264). You can also try [H.265](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.265)  which can give you another 25–50% reduction in file size (again depending on your encoding configuration) but will take more computational power (or time).

[added 3/16/22]

My original answer was off the mark. The reason you're getting 2 different results (cli vs. Python) is because the filters are not the same:

Command Line: `scale=320:240`. Pretty straight forward, output would be 320-px wide by 240-px high

Python expression: `'scale=.{x}/{y}*iw:ih'`. Although the values of `x` and `y` are not disclosed, the height remains the same while the width is modified by some funny math (`x` representing the fractional part of the numerator divided by the `y` as the denominator, times the input width). If your intention is to output the same dimension video as the cli case with `x=320` and `y=240` then the expression should read simply: `scale={x}:{y}`.

Comment: What does the command line normally use?

Comment: It does the H.264 CRF 1-pass encoding with `-crf 23` (according the link above). Your current results indicate that the input video quality is not very high so you can crank up that number till you see difference in the video quality.

Comment: Irregardless what I set CRF('-crf:23') to the file size remains the same. I can't get preset('-preset:medium') to work at all to be able to see what effect it might have.

Comment: What happens if you go all the way and use `-crf 50`? My experience agrees with the wiki: "the CRF value +6 results in roughly half the bitrate / file size, while -6 leads to roughly twice the bitrate"

Comment: I still get the same file size and bitrate. Even at 1 I get the same bitrate and file size.

Comment: Are the numbers on your post `3523 bytes` and `3765 bytes`? If so, the video must be really short. Could it be that your video is highly predictable (like simple geometric shapes)? If so, h265 may not be able to do any better job, Have you tried h265?

Comment: The video is only around a minute long with a guy standing talking to the camera with not much background imagery showing. As I asked in the original post, why does the command line conversion give such a smaller file versus the python conversion? What is the difference between the two versions of converting the file with the same ffmpeg? So I tried a longer, more complex video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T1tV-ovGPyc and both versions came across the same size again.

Comment: I think I know what's going on. Your Python filter definition seems incorrect. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: I updated my original post as well with a new video tried all the way through the combos. But in trying your updated answer with subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', input_file, 'scale={x}:{y}', output_file]) it does nothing, whether leaving the crop statement alone or changing it to crop('C:/filename.mp4', 'C:/filename1.mp4', x=320, y=240). Either way it does not do any conversion.

Comment: On your error statement, that's because you're missing the option `-filter:v`. Also, the `crf` experiment was to check if the problem is in the encoder (which it's not).

Comment: What would help is for you to post the full python ffmpeg command (`shlex.join([...])` instead of `subprocess.run([...])`) and the setup log messages of the ffmpeg run.

Comment: With the exception of the subprocess line change everything else has remained constant with the code at the top of the thread. I had seen subprocess being used elsewhere so it was what I have been working with. In python it never opens up the encoding screen unless its going to encode it and other than the error mentioned above I haven't been getting an error, it just has been encoding.

Comment: Took a few minutes after reading your reply before I reread it again and figured out what you meant by the setup log. I've included it for both command line and python read outs.

Comment: If you could format the logs, I can see it better, but note the difference: cli `Output #0, mp4, ... Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 ..., 320x240 [SAR 9:8 DAR 3:2]` vs. Python `Output #0 ... Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 ... 540x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 3:2]`. There lies the Python issue. Your scaling filter is not setup correctly (it's not doing anything as the input is also `540x360`). So, check what the output string of `'scale=.{}/{}*iw:ih'.format(x, y)` looks like.

Comment: Okay, I think I updated it to make it look better. How do I check the output string, definitely a little dumb in this respect of things?

Comment: Comment out the `subprocess.call(...)` line (add `#` at the beginning of the line) and add a new line right before it, which reads `print('scale=.{}/{}*iw:ih'.format(x, y))`, It should show what the scale filter argument looks like.

Comment: Not sure in this case what it is suppose to give me???, the output video resolution or the input video resolution. It comes up 320:240. I tried it with all three videos, the original, the cli and the py and all came up the same, hence why I think it is giving me output video.